# Xcode 6.1 UIImageView disappearing when resizing

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard

Currently I have this bug that occurs  when I have 2 UIImageView on the storyboard and when I try to resize one of them, the other one will disappear?

Comment: Please provide some more info . code or image what you've done.

Comment: [link](http://puu.sh/cxN82/1dba32e280.png) is how it initially looks like

This is what happens when I try to resize one of those images and one of them will disappear
[link](http://puu.sh/cxNb6/962ae25758.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encounter this. I just manually adjust my `UIImageView` dimensions in Size inspector to prevent this from happening. Major Xcode 6.1 bug I think.

It also happens with other interface builder elements i.e. `UILabel`, `UITextView`, `UIButton`, etc. The glitch is only `UIImageViews` are the ones that resizes to 0,0,0,0. I wonder if Apple fixed this with Xcode 6.1.1 GM seed.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the image view hasn't been given any auto layout constraints. Super annoying.